# "missing right parenthesis"

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to update a table with the following information

```
INSERT INTO CS350REGT ("Region Code", "Region Name", "HQ", "Manager") 
SELECT ('NW', 'Northwest', 'Spokane, WA', '944 58 432')FROM DUAL UNION,
SELECT ('S', 'Southern', 'Dallas, TX', )FROM DUAL UNION,
SELECT ('NE', 'New England', 'Albany, NY', '900 58 472') FROM DUAL UNION,
SELECT ('HQ', 'Headquarters Staff', 'Waltham, MA', ) FROM DUAL UNION,
SELECT ('SE', 'Southeast', 'Miami, FL', '785 02 675') FROM DUAL UNION
```

After running it it shows a "missing right parenthesis" error message. Note that I am using Oracle and wont let me use INSERT ALL command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple errors:

- The comma isn't appropriate.
- The parentheses are incorrect.
- Some rows are missing values (which should presumably be `NULL`).

Try something like this:

```
INSERT INTO CS350REGT ("Region Code", "Region Name", "HQ", "Manager") 
    SELECT 'NW', 'Northwest', 'Spokane, WA', '944 58 432' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'S', 'Southern', 'Dallas, TX', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'NE', 'New England', 'Albany, NY', '900 58 472' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'HQ', 'Headquarters Staff', 'Waltham, MA', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'SE', 'Southeast', 'Miami, FL', '785 02 675' FROM DUAL
```